# SonarQube 9.0 - FindBugs/SpotBugs plugin?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, findbugs, spotbugs

Small question regarding SonarQube, the 9.0 version of SonarQube.

I went to the market place after installation in order to download some plugins, and found the FindBugs/SpotBugs plugin is absent.

May I ask what is the root cause, and how to perform analysis with FindBugs/SpotBugs please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin is unavailable in the SonarQube marketplace because there is no compatible version with SonarQube 9.X.

The matrix is here: https://update.sonarsource.org/plugins/compatibility-matrix.html

You have 3 options:

1. revert SonarQube to 8.X (e.g. 8.9 LTS) and wait with migration to SonarQube 9.X till a compatible version is released
2. stop using the Findbugs plugin
3. fix the plugin and install it manually (an issue about SonarQube 9.X support: [ClassNotFoundException with sonarqube 9](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/issues/368); maybe there are more)